# android espresso Must run under a registering instrumentation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I want to use espresso classes outside of android test package. I added espresso with compile keyword into gradle file and I access espresso classes into normal app classes. But, When I run app, I get an exception as "android espresso Must run under a registering instrumentation."

Our Android studio 3.0.0 and espress 3.0.0.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want them outside of androidTest package? Do you have several modules for which you want to run the tests and your intention is to avoid configuring Espresso for each one?

Comment: My project is about view type detection ,but my codes not working full correct. Thus,I want to use only espresso's click some text methods into normal app activity(espresso automatically know view types).